# How to get Accept-Language request header value on client

Tags: angularjs

I need to know `Accept-Language` request header value in order to make a translation on a page. I've tried to create an interceptor like

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);
```

, but in the method

```
request: function (config) {
```

of my interceptor I don't see `Accept-Language` header. I see Accept, Cache-Control, If-Modified-Since, Pragma but in the browser I do see `Accept-Language`.

Comment: you should have an headers object or array where you can add your header information.
On Angular2/4 you have something like this:

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept-Language', ''xyz);

this.http.post(url, data, {
  headers: headers
})

Comment: @moohkooh When I do a request browser sets the language code to the header and I need to read that. I dont need to set it, I need to know the value that browser set up.

Answer (score 2):

Not all request headers are available in AngularJS request interceptor's config parameter. other header values are browser settings that are added while constructing the request.

You could use, but i'm not sure it gives you the right language.

> var language = window.navigator.userLanguage or 
>   window.navigator.language;

Only the server can see the value of `Accept-Language`. So i think the best way is to get this value from the server response-body and memorize it in you cookies (name example AcceptLanguageCookie) and after that you can overide the `Accept-Language` someway like this in your interceptor.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
  // set Accept-Language header on all requests
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept-Language"] = $cookies.get("AcceptLanguageCookie");
}]);
```